# UIBezierPath Shadow effect

Tags: ios, uikit, core-graphics, shadow, uibezierpath

Currently I am working on a paint app for iOS. I am stuck with applying shadow effect to a particular drawn path. I have use UIBezierpath to draw paths. Is there any way to apply shadow effect on UIBezierpath?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0, 5), 5.0, [[UIColor blackColor]CGColor]);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
```

Something like this may help u..

Answer (score 5):

```
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeZero, 20, [path.color CGColor])
```

I think this may help you to show shadow effect